# Sticky headers not maintaining width when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some table headers which I planned on making sticky (fixed) as the user scrolls down the page, but they currently shrink when the sticky is activated, I would like them to inherit the widths of the headers, but they shrink to the size of the text at the moment. 
My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var stickyNavTop = $('.th').offset().top;
```

`SOLUTION:`

```
 $(".th th").each(function(){$(this).width($(this).width());});
 $('.th').width($('.th').width());

var stickyNav = function(){  
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
    $('.th').addClass('sticky');  
} else {  
    $('.th').removeClass('sticky');   
}  
};  

stickyNav();  

$(window).scroll(function() {  
    stickyNav();  
});  
});
```

My HTML:

```
<table class="mGrid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="1"
style="width:98%;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr class="th">
    <th scope="col">Membership No.</th>
    <th scope="col">Surname</th>
    <th scope="col">Other Name(s)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="2" class="formInput">
        <label for="2">Membership No.</label>
        <input name="2" type="text" value="AH6973" id="2"
        class="required" style="width:60px;" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="3" class="formInput">
        <label for="3">Surname</label>
        <input name="3" type="text" value="CARTER" id="3"
        style="width:100px;" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="4" class="formInput">
        <label for="4">Other Name(s)</label>
        <input name="4" type="text" value="RAYMOND" id="4"
        style="width:150px;" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

my CSS:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
    color: #fff !important;
    background: #666;
    border-left: solid 1px #525252;
    font-size: 1.0em;
}
```

(This is modelled to be the same as the header style, it's just the width shrinks to fit the width of the text at the moment. I tried to edit the header style but it's apparently read-only  `"'HeaderStyle' property is read-only and cannot be set."`

Comment: We don't want your ASP, we want your resulting HTML markup... this is front end stuff my friend.

Comment: Anyway I believe that's not possible. I tried it once. I would recommend you to create an absolute positioned element on scrolling at the top of the page.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I've replaced the .aspx with the HTML now, I thought it would be difficult to do but didn't think it was impossible!

Comment: Well, as I said, I would do an an absolute positioned element instead of trying to break the table. The position fixed that you are trying to apply will break any connection with the table and therefore you will need to apply styles to accommodate it to the table structure, which is... like creating the element i suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add this line before your function definition:

```
$('th').width($('th').width());
```

Full JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var stickyNavTop = $('.th').offset().top;  

    $('th').width($('th').width());

    var stickyNav = function(){  
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
            $('.th').addClass('sticky');  
        } else {  
            $('.th').removeClass('sticky');   
        }  
    };  

    stickyNav();  

    $(window).scroll(function() {  
        stickyNav();  
    });  
});
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your answer, it now fills the page more, but doesn't match up with my columns still. 
I also didn't mention that my headers overflow horizontally, and so ideally the headers wouldn't be fixed when scrolling horizontally, only vertically

Comment: Hi Matt, I've edited the original question to include the solution now, I didn't mention my th's were different sizes, so I added an extra line to your solution, thanks

Comment: upvoted! i have the same problem here, my headers would also be fixed vertically but not horizontally, any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

here is a common solution, it auto detects each sub-element's width and height and reflect when scrolling, it is something like following:

```
var $this = $(this),
      top = $this.offset().top,
      left = $this.offset().left,
      width = $this.width(),
      height = $this.height(),
      widthArr = [],
      heightArr = [];
    $this.find("*").each(function(i, e) {
      widthArr.push($(this).width());
      heightArr.push($(this).height());
    });

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() >= top) {
    $this.css({
      position: "fixed",
      top: 0,
      left: left,
      "z-index": 100,
      width: width,
      height: height
    });

    $this.find("*").each(function(i, e) {
      $(this).width(widthArr[i]);
      $(this).height(heightArr[i]);
    });
  } else {
      // to be implemented
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by common? Is there a github repo for this?

Comment: @Danger14 Here it is: https://github.com/shaogbi/FrontEnd/blob/master/jQuery/auto-header.js

Answer (score 1):

My solution to avoid column width changes : cloning the header.  (Thanks to @Matt for the line: `$('th').width($('th').width());` and his solution.)

JS

```
var stickyNavTop = jQuery('thead tr:first-child').offset().top;

// init state
var stickState = (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > stickyNavTop);

var stickyNav = function() {
    var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    // state has changed?
    if (stickState != (scrollTop > stickyNavTop)) {

        // remember/catch new state
        stickState = (scrollTop > stickyNavTop);

        if (stickState) {  
            jQuery('thead tr:first-child th').each(
                function() { jQuery(this).width( jQuery(this).width() ); }
            );

            // cloning the header : the original columns won't move
            jQuery('thead tr:first-child')
                .clone()
                .prependTo(jQuery('thead'))
                .addClass('sticky');

        } else {  
            jQuery('tr.sticky').remove();
        }  

    }
};  

jQuery(window).scroll(function() { 
    stickyNav();  
});  

stickyNav();
```

CSS

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```